# MySQL: Count entry once every month until entry change

Tags: mysql

I need to make a list of how the score of each customer have chagned during time.

My problem is that I do not have a score for each month I want to look at. Hence I need to count the previous entry as the score for this month.

On top of that, if there is registered two scores in the same month, only the newest score should count in that month

My table with data looks something like this:

```
| id | customer_id | score | created_at |   
| 1  |     1       |  4    | 2016-05-01 |   
| 2  |     2       |  4    | 2016-05-01 |  
| 3  |     3       |  4    | 2016-05-01 |   
| 4  |     1       |  3    | 2016-05-15 |  
| 5  |     2       |  2    | 2016-06-01 |   
| 6  |     3       |  2    | 2016-06-13 |   
| 7  |     2       |  4    | 2016-07-01 |  
| 8  |     2       |  2    | 2016-08-21 |  
| 9  |     1       |  2    | 2016-08-01 |  
| 10 |     1       |  1    | 2016-08-31 |
```

I would like a result like this:

```
|customer_id |   MONTH     | Score |
|     1      |   2016-05   |   3   |
|     2      |   2016-05   |   4   |
|     3      |   2016-05   |   4   |
|     1      |   2016-06   |   3   |
|     2      |   2016-06   |   2   |
|     3      |   2016-06   |   2   |
|     1      |   2016-07   |   3   |
|     2      |   2016-07   |   4   |
|     3      |   2016-07   |   2   |
|     1      |   2016-08   |   1   |
|     2      |   2016-08   |   2   |
|     3      |   2016-08   |   2   |
|     1      |   2016-09   |   1   |
|     2      |   2016-09   |   2   |
|     3      |   2016-09   |   2   |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following QUERY:

```
SELECT tt.customer_id,CONCAT(YEAR(tt.created_at),'-',MONTH(tt.created_at)) AS MONTH,tt.score 
FROM myTable tt INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id,customer_id,YEAR(created_at) AS selYear,
MONTH(created_at) AS selMonth FROM myTable GROUP BY customer_id,YEAR(created_at),MONTH(created_at)) sel_tt
ON tt.id=sel_tt.max_id AND tt.customer_id=sel_tt.customer_id AND YEAR(tt.created_at)=sel_tt.selYear 
AND MONTH(tt.created_at)=sel_tt.selMonth ORDER BY tt.customer_id,tt.created_at
```